# how can I not refresh a page when there is authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, timeout

I have a authentication timeout = 2 min and when I am in a view and do nothing for 2 min, I will be redirected to login page - that's good. Now I want another view which I use iframe and shows another page which is like enrollment but handles by somebody else. Now while I am in another website:

1) how can I extend my website timeout and
2) I can see I have a header in the page like , which refreshes my page every 2 min. I don't want this to happen as I am in the middle of something in the enrollment website and it resets everything. This headers is added after I added authentication to the web config, but I need it for other pages.

Can anyone advise the best approach that I can extend the timeout while we use iframe.

Thanks

Comment: Show your page header which contains refresh command. Site timeout when idle can be extended by editing web.config or changing IIS application pool settings.

Comment: <meta content="60" http-equiv="refresh" name="refresh" />

Comment: could you please send me some examples on how to update them when the page's loaded